# Is there a way to have a variable width mixin for a div that is 96% wide for small sized devices and 62% wide for larger screens?

Tags: css, variables, sass, width

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fH1l.jpg) I'd like to create a scss variable that changes its size extending 62% of the screen for large screens and 96% for small sized devices like phones. I'd like to acheive this without using media queries.

```
$width-small : 100% - 4%; // For phones and small devices

$width-large :  100% - 32%; // For large devices, laptops and Desktops

@mixin variable-width($width-small, $width-large) {

@if $width-small = '> 768px' {
    width: calc(100% - 4%);
}
@else { 
    width: calc(100% - 38%);
}
```

//This is the idea, I know its not correct but its a start

I'd basically like the screen size to adjust slowly as you shrink and expand it, and not jump as would be seen with a media query.

I would like to do this in scss as a function preferably.

Please see image link for clarity. Thank you.

Comment: Do responsive without media queries is little bit hard, but, if you wanna try, go with CSS calc() function.

Comment: Yeah I usually do the calc function for heights, but do you know how you would do it for a variable width container? So for phone size 540px and below I want it to span the width of the screen with 2% margin on each side for a total width of 96%. For the largest size I would like it to span only 62% with perhaps an auto margin on each side. Is this possible?

Comment: scss gets compiled to css and the browsers use css so there is no way of writing this in css without mediaqueries. they act like an if else structure in css.

Comment: The problem is that with media queries it doesn't make sense to have any more than say 4. Phone device, Tablet, Desktop display, and Large Desktop display, anything beyond that is sort of overkill. Besides that, when you get to the media query your divs tend to "jump". That being said, with this function I would like to have the div within the window resize, if say a client wants to shrink their window and work on something else in another window...

Answer (score 0):

So I was searching for something viable on the web and found Ana Tudor's answer in codepen. No media queries just pure elegant beautiful scss. Thank you Ana all credit goes to you.

```
@mixin proportional-box($a: 1, $b: $a) {
position: absolute;
top: 0; left: calc(50vw - #{$a/$b/2*100vh});
width: $a/$b*100vh; height: 100vh;

@media (max-aspect-ratio: #{$a}/#{$b}) {
top: calc(50vh - #{$b/$a/2*100vw}); left: 0;
width: 100vw; height: $b/$a*100vw;
 }
}

html { 
background: #f9f9f9; 
}

body { 
margin: 0; 
}

.slide {
@include proportional-box(4, 3);
}
```

Check it out in action https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jYqzPX